# ListPlot with Joined set to True

Tags: plotting

Let

```
f[x_]=9x^2-2x-3;
```

I want to make a table of `f` at `x ={-1, -0.5, 0, 0.5, 1, 1.5, 2}`.
Plot these values with `ListPlot` + option `Joined` set to `True`
Make a "normal" plot of `f` on the interval [-1, 2]

---

```
Table[{f[x]}, {x, -1, 2, 0.5}]

Curves := Riffle[Table[{f[x]}, {x, -1, 2, 0.5}], Table[{f[x]}, {x, -1, 2, 0.5}]]
ListLinePlot[Curves]
Plot[f[x], {x, -1, 2}]
```

Is this ok for this task?
Because i think with `Joined` the points dont get joined but are still separate, but I don't know if that's normal because of `ListPlot`. And with `Plot` I don't think I got the right function, but if I do:

```
Plot[f[x], {x, -1, 2}]
```

then I miss the points $-.5, .5, 1.5$.
Or shouldn't that be a problem since the question is not that specific?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is this what you want to do? `f[x_] = 9 x^2 - 2 x - 3;
Curves = Table[{x, f[x]}, {x, -1, 2, 0.5}];
ListLinePlot[Curves, InterpolationOrder -> 3]
Plot[f[x], {x, -1, 2}]`

Comment: Yes i think it is.

Comment: But the next question was: describe the difference of the plots, where i expected listlineplot to be less accurate

Comment: remove the `InterpolationOrder->3` and it will be so. Interpolation was done precisely to make it look smooth!

Comment: ok thanks shouldve come up with that myself...

Comment: b.t.w. you might want to have a look at the editing tips on how to format you question

Comment: a late welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it
too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 2) [`Read the FAQs`](http://tinyurl.com/cacvex2)!  3) When you see good Q&A, vote them up by [`clicking 
the gray triangles`](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system 
is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge.  ALSO, remember to 
accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [`by clicking the checkmark sign`](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)`

Answer (score 4):

It seems you want to do something like this:

```
f[x_] = 9 x^2 - 2 x - 3; 
 Curves = Table[{x, f[x]}, {x, -1, 2, 0.5}]; 
 Show[{
     ListLinePlot[Curves, PlotStyle -> Red, 
     Epilog -> {AbsolutePointSize[Large], Point /@ Curves}] , 
 Plot[f[x], {x, -1, 2}, PlotStyle -> Dashed]
 }]
```

[image: plot versus list lineplot]

which shows the difference between the Built in `Plot` and `ListLinePlot` routines.